# Git: How to checkout branch on case insensitive filesystems? Git thinks I have untracked files in working tree while I do not

Tags: git, macos, version-control, filesystems

```
nowaker@nwkr-newmbp ~/projects/my-project (git)-[version-pin] % git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Readme.md
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

```
% git status
On branch version-pin
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The only difference between current branch and master is I renamed the filename from Readme.md to README.md on my current branch. `master` still has Readme.md. Because a default Mac OSX filesystem is formatted as case insensitive, git thinks I have untracked files in working tree while I do not.

What is the best way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git checkout --force`.

```
% git checkout master --force
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase

You probably want to make change to your git config

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

Comment: Don't do that: Git sets `core.ignorecase` itself when you create the repository, based on the behavior of the OS / file-system. It's an informational flag that Git uses to know what will happen when Git does various file system operations. If you change it, but the OS still behaves the same, you're lying to Git, and if Git then misbehaves, that's your fault. :-) That's why the documentation to which you linked says "Modifying this value may result in unexpected behavior."

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 files won't be changed for the foreseeable future, you could use `git update-index --assume-unchanged $path` or `git update-index --skip-worktree $path` to suppress the error. Later, you can use `--no-assume-unchanged` or `--no-skip-worktree` to cancel the effect.

But, the best way is to rename one of them a different name and commit the change on a case-sensitive system.